# How can I insert and save data into database using Visual Studio and C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public string ss = "Data Source=D\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=gym;Integrated Security=True";

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string q2 = "insert into gym.dbo.customer (name, weight, height, add_class, gender, fees) values ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.comboBox1.Text + "','" + this.comboBox2.Text + "','" + this.comboBox3.Text + " ') ;";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ss);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q2, con);
    SqlDataReader read;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to our gym");

        while (read.Read()) { };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

How can I insert and save data into the database using Visual Studio and C#?

This code throws an error. Anyone please give the suggestion to me to solve the error.

[**image description**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Mjk.png)

Comment: What error?  Also there's some very bad practice going on there - have a read up on SQL Injection.

Comment: invalid object name gym.dbo.customer                                                                      it gives me this error  .. no i haven't what is SQL injection??  @C.Knight

Comment: The insert statement probably needs to be executed using `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteNonQuery`. It doesn't return a record set, so `ExecuteReader` probably throws.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `gym` at the beginning.

Comment: You probably just want `dbo.customer`, not `gym.dbo.customer`.

Comment: SQL Injection is a form of attack that (in your case) would allow the user to do whatever they want to your database (upto and including deleting it entirely) simply by choosing what they enter in your textboxes approriately

Comment: if i use dbo.customer only it give me the same error which is invalid  bject name aslo when i use executescalar or ExecuteNonQuery it gives me that error(Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\OOP_Project\OOP_Project\Form2.cs 52 24 OOP_Project
)

Comment: Don't assign the result of ExecuteNonQuery to a SqlDataReader. It's result is `int`, which is the number of rows affected by the query - should be one.

Comment: so how could i assign it??

Comment: I think your connection string is not assigned properly while execute command

Answer (score 3):

At first make sure your the data type of different column  of customer table.
Then make sure what type of data you have to save for combobox.

you have to get the selected value from your Combobox. combobox1,combobox2,combobox3  retuns only the class name

```
 System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
```

Besides others, it is recommended to use parameter .. like this:
You can follow this example

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\abdul samad\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\newpro\newpro\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        try
        {

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO registor (Name, FullName, Password, Email, Gander) VALUES (@Name,@Fullname,@Password,@Email, @Gander)"))
            {

                cmd.Connection = con;   
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", txtfname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fullname", txtfname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", txtpass.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", txtemail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gander", comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem));

                con.Open()
                if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) 
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Record inserted"); 
                }
                else
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Record failed");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error during insert: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaLîa MaHmôud,if it is useful please marked as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
            { 
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into customer (name,weight,height,add_class,gender,fees) values(@name,@weight,@height,@add_class,@gender,@fees)", con); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", this.textBox1.Text); 
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
                con.Open(); 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                con.Close(); 
            }
```

Comment: change sqlcommand inside as 

"insert into customer (name,weight,height,add_class,gender,fees) values(@name,@weight,@height,@add_class,@gender,@fees)"

Answer (score 0):

The comments are getting a bit busy, so this is the sort of thing you need to do (including parameterising the query):

Specifically, you don't need a reader for an insert statement as it doesn't return a result set.

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sql = "insert into dbo.customer ...";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ss))
    {

        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql , con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to our gym");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi check that customer table is available in gym Database.
else try this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e760744-442b-44c7-8116-77136e12a898/error-invalid-object-name-tablename-but-the-tables-exist-in-the-database?forum=sqlgetstarted)

Answer (score 0):

I found that your connection string declaration is wrong

```
public string ss = "Data Source=D\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=gym;Integrated Security=True";
```

need to update like below

```
public string ss = "Data Source=abc\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=gym; user id=sa; Password=123456";
```

Data source will be not be D, It should be Server name.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDZdQ.png)